# My Application stucking when it on debug mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I build winform application.
When I try to debug my project, I do rebuild and the debug.
The application run, but stuck before the winform  is visible.
if I press the Pause button (in Visual Studio) and the the play button, the winform released.
If I debug the application line by line, the winform is not stuck.

What can I do?
I don't know where to begin.

Thanks a lot

Comment: try break, break all - it might get you to a place, then call stack + what Tigran suggested. And do you have a full blown app, or some small example?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable [First Chance Exceptions](http://florianreischl.blogspot.it/2010/01/how-to-enable-first-chance-exceptions.html) in Visual Studio (if they are not yet enabled) and see if there is any exception that disturbs *expected* execution flow in any way.
2. Use [Eqatec](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/) profiler to profile app, to see what happens on startup.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem was that the "WindowState" property of my form was on "Minimized" state. That was stupid mistake. Thanks.